# Check and calculate the values next to the current index key array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
 if (theArray[i-1] < theArray.Length && theArray[i-1] != null)
```

Is what i got after some research. But it gives just gives me out of index error, because i do i-1.

But i want the if statement to check whether the key/index on i-1 exists, then do something..

See what i want to do is plus the values of the indexes next to the current index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
{
    Left = 0;
    Right = 0;
            if (i != 0)
            {
                Left = theArray[i - 1];
            }
            if (theArray[i + 1] < theArray.Length)
            {
                Right = theArray[i + 1];
            }

    calc = Left + Right;
    output2.Text += calc + ", ";
}
```

So if the left is there then change the left value (default is 0, right and left), and if right is there then change the right value. And then calculate both values taken from theArray[].

E.g if its on theArray[16] it should take the left, theArray[15] and theArray[17] and plus together.

Comment: Is `theArray` meant to hold indices?

Comment: `i-1` will fail on the first iteration, as it will try to access an index of `-1`.

Comment: @Oded: I'm worried about `theArray[i-1] < theArray.Length` statement. Do you also feel it may not be right?

Comment: Since Left and Right can be added together but also can be null they must be something that has an overloaded + operator. I agree that it is essential to know what they hold since obviously it can't be integers.

Comment: As said in question, i would like to take the two next-to index values from theArray[]. So lets say theArray[1] is 8 and theArray[3] is 92. OK. Then now the current i in the foreach is 2 then it should take the 8 (which is the value from index 1 ) and the 92 (which is the value from index 3 ) and plus them together which would be 100.

Comment: In this case, why do you check for null? An integer can't be null.

Comment: Can you please stop changing the code sample people are using to answer your question?

Comment: @Oded sorry i just changed it so none gets comfused

Comment: @ILoveFortran in this current code in the question i check against null so it skip the code when i==0

Comment: @Karem: `Left` and `Right` vars are not used in this given example. Oded is right (so am I :)) that i-1 will fail in first iteration. You need to check for `i-1` evaluated index to be greater than 0.

Comment: "I check against null so it skip the code when i==0." I am sorry but that makes no sense. You check for null if an object is null but if the elements in the array are integers than they can't be null. So I have to ask: are the elements meant to be integers?

Comment: @Karem: You changed the code again?? :(

Comment: @ILoveFortran: As per his examples, yes this is array of integers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
if(i < theArray.Length)
```

Or possibly:

```
if(i < theArray.Length && theArray[i] != null)
```

I would normally be using `i` in a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
```

---

Update:

You can't use `i-1`, because on the first iteration, when `i == 0`, this would evaluate to `-1`. This is an illegal index in an array.

---

Update 2:

I think I understand what you are trying to do now. Here is one way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
{
    Left = 0;
    Right = 0;
    if (i > 0)
    {
        Left = theArray[i-1];
    }
    if (i < theArray.Length - 1)
    {
        Right = theArray[i+1];
    }

    calc = Left + Right;
    output2.Text += calc + ", ";
}
```

Comment: Ok why cant i set my Left variable to the value in theArray[i - 1]; ? how should i do this if i only can get to theArray[i]

Comment: @Karem - You might be able to. However, you have not given enough context for me to determine. Please update your question and add more detail such as what exactly you are tyring to achieve, and the full code sample (with where `i` is defined etc).

Comment: yes but thats why i would like to check first if i-1 exists because i know it is an illegal index in the start when i==0

Comment: I just tried wrap if(i != 0){ around the if statement Left, but still error at theArray[i-1] line (which only should be executed if i isnt 0)

Comment: @Karem - I just don't get the need for `i-1` to begin with. Assuming you just want every pair of items in the array, you don't need to `i-1` at all.

Comment: As said in question, i would like to take the two next-to index values from theArray[]. So lets say theArray[1] is 8 and theArray[3] is 92. OK. Then now the current i in the foreach is 2 then it should take the 8 (which is the value from index 1 ) and the 92 (which is the value from index 3 ) and plus them together which would be 100.

Comment: @Karem - Answer updated with code I believe will do what you are looking for. You need to check for the array bounds before trying to access array items via the index.

Comment: @Nayan - Yeah. Very confusing to answer, as OP keeps editing his code sample :(

Comment: @Oded sorry guys. Ok almost there, i get error on Right = theArray[i + 1];

Comment: @Karem - Sorry about that `=` sign was wrong on the test before assigning to `Right`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `i` is a valid array index, you can do this:

```
if(i >= theArray.GetLowerBound(0) && i <= theArray.GetUpperBound(0))
```

That will only be necessary in rare edge cases, however, so it's more practical to do this:

```
if(i >= 0 && i < theArray.Length)
```

Once you know that it's a valid index, you can check for `null` if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question whether the **index** or the **array value with given index** exists?
In case of array you can always be sure that index n "exists" if  0 < n < array.Length.
If you want to check for the array value, first check for (n > 0) for the index "under" and (n < array.Length) for the index "over"

Answer (score -1):

I think in addition to what Oded said, the correct expression might be:

```
if (i < theArray.Length && i > 0 && theArray[i-1] != null)
```

because you are checking value at `i-1` index.

Comment: the "i < theArray.Length" is wrong since array is accessed with i-1

Comment: It cannot be :) You're just taking revenge. Grow up Jim!

Comment: You are the one that should grow up and be able to admit when you are wrong

Answer (score -1):

From your code, it appears that "i" is one-based and your array indexes are zero-based. So you could use:

```
if ( (i > 0) && (i <= theArray.Length) && (theArray[i-1] != null) )
```

Comment: `i <= theArray.Length` will lead to out-of-bound.

Comment: @Nayan: YOU ARE WRONG, the array is accessed with: i-1

Comment: There is not enough data to show that index expression will always evaluate to be < array's length. Hence, this answer may lead to exception.

Comment: @Nayan: WRONG. There is no way that my answer could cause an exception. If i == theArray.Length then i-1 must be less than theArray.Length. Simple arithmetic.

Comment: Based on updated code, yes your code will work. But before that, it could not guarantee the safety.

Comment: @Nayan: I never changed the code, I added comment about the array being zero-based. Code was always correct. I am waiting for an apology and a removal of the down vote.

Comment: Jim, I'm talking about the updation of question by Karem, not yours. Ok, if you are that offended by -1 voting, its time locked now. I'll not apologize for your inaccurate answer. Ciao!

Comment: @Nayan: You are wrong again. My answer was correct for original question. You just don't seem to be able to admit it.